# Can a lightsaber block a disruptor rifle bolt?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, lightsaber

Since disruptor rifles are basically laser rifles, I'd imagine they fire some sort of proton beam instead of plasmified gas like regular blasters.

Since the generally accepted theory is that lightsaber blades consist of plasma contained in a toroidal magnetic field, would a disruptor beam just pass straight through?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that a lightsaber would be highly vulnerable to the effects of a disruptor. In canon, I just think there's insufficient info to speculate further.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume we refer to the Star Wars version of the [disruptor rifle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Disruptor_rifle).

> A disruptor rifle was a vicious and devastating weapon that disintegrated its target. It tore apart its victim at the molecular level, destroying their body tissues and bypassing most sorts of personal energy shields. A disruptor weapon shot a constant beam of energy that would travel in a straight direction until it hit solid matter.

Energy shields are made of plasma. Lightsaber blades are also made of plasma. Disruptor beams are made of highly concentrated plasma. It stands to reason that if a disruptor beam can pass through a plasma shield, then a lightsaber should be either similarly useless or ineffective at best.

This is demonstrated in the game *Jedi Outcast*. A DXR-6 disruptor rifle fires a charged beam. Unlike normal blaster bolts, a disruptor bolt from this rifle cannot be deflected by the lightsaber, only absorbed, albeit with difficulty. Quick shots cannot be easily anticipated and absorbed, and often not completely, therefore still inflicting some damage to a Jedi protected only by a lightsaber. At full charge, however, it can cause heavy damage even to a Jedi, and if not successfully blocked, it can still cause complete vapourisation altogether.

Comment: This appears to be an answer based in Legends, correct?

Comment: Yes. There is a new ion disruptor in Battlefront, but it's more anti-armor and only lethal to flesh and blood in a direct hit